# Prove the following inequality for $a,b,c,d>0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c,d>0$. Is there an easy way to see that the following inequality is true:

$$4(a+b+c+d)+2(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)-4(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)-(a^2b+ab^2+a^2c+ac^2+a^2d+ad^2+b^2c+bc^2+b^2d+bd^2+c^2d+cd^2)+2(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2+c^2d^2)-(ab^2c^2d^2+a^2bc^2d^2+a^2b^2cd^2+a^2b^2c^2d)+4a^2b^2c^2d^2\geq 0$$

This has naturally come up in my research, and it seems like something like this should be easy to see right away, seeing as it is very symmetric. Mathematica confirms this inequality (note that it has equality when all the variables are $0$ or $1$). However, I haven't been able to prove it yet.

Comment: You may provide the  expression (e.g. Maple) for people to copy.

Comment: I think the condition should be $a, b, c, d \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: You may use the BW (Buffalo Way) i.e. $a = \frac{1}{1 + x}, \cdots$.